# My wife is pregnant and I don't want to be part of it, what I should do?

Tags: parents, pregnancy

My wife is pregnant with her 8th child. She has 3 from her first marriage, 2 more with another relation, and I married her and we have 2 more. She got pregnant while she has both an IUD and is on birth control.

We barely have enough money, we work a lot. She wants to keep this kid and I don't. All the kids range from 19, 18, 15, 10, 9, 5, 4.

I think it is irresponsible for us to have another kid when we have so many and it is difficult to raise these 7 kids, let alone have one more.

What can I do to change her mind?

Comment: That or opinion based; I can't see a useful objective answer here really.  In particular, given she's already pregnant, this would be a _highly_ inflammatory question if it's allowed to proceed.

Comment: I can see opinion based, but not so sure about duplicate. I'd think an 8th child in a patchwork family is quite different from a 4th child in the same relationship.

Comment: @microtherion - How to deal with it doesn't really matter if the family is mixed or not, does it? There are only so many things on can do.

Comment: I would think that the family dynamics in a mixed family are different, and quite likely more complex, than in a non-mixed family.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're perfect duplicates; at the end of the day the best answers to that question are also good answers to this one.